Find difference between two lines
I am trying to find a distance that does not overlap. In the image, I have two lines plotted in folium. I want to calculate the distance where the red line is not covered by the blue line.
For context, the red line is a hypothetical route taken via bike, and the blue lines are bike lanes. Ultimately, I want to say x distance of travel occurred on roads where a bike lane did not exist.

Blue lines can be loaded from a geojson located here. The red route can be recreated using openrouteservice and the code below:
client = ors.Client(key=key) 
coords = [[-79.3873, 43.65049], [-79.3641171, 43.6613642]]`
route = client.directions(coordinates=coords,
                      profile='cycling-regular',
                      format='geojson')

route_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(route)
lane_df = lane_df = geopandas.read_file(lane_file_from_link)

I had attempted using geopandas.difference, but did not get the intended result.
route_df['geometry'].difference(lane_df).plot() with the following warning UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.
But it simply returns the entire route. Unsure how to proceed next.

The ideal result would be the following. 
UPDATE:
Incorporating Bera's suggestion of adding a buffer, I got to my desired outcome. There was some trial and error to get the buffering just right. I also had to change the CRS (although I'm not 100% sure what I am doing there as this is all new to me) to avoid the following error: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.
route_df2 = route_df.to_crs(crs=3857) 
route_df.geometry = route_df2.buffer(distance=1, cap_style='flat')
route_df = route_df.to_crs(crs=4326) 

lane_df2 = lane_df.to_crs(crs=3857) 
lane_df.geometry = lane_df2.buffer(distance=4, cap_style='flat')
lane_df = lane_df.to_crs(crs=4326)

diff = geopandas.overlay(route_df,lane_df, how='difference')
diff.plot()



Try diff = gpd.overlay(lane_df, route_df, how="difference")

@Bera the route does not show at all. And if I flip route_df and lane_df. I get the same image as the difference example shown.

The warning UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different is probably important. You are doing a row by row difference which I think is not what you want. You need to be working with the actual geometries and probably want the red ones to be a MultiLine

And next time, please edit your original question, rather than deleting and reposting

@IanTurton 1. Right now the route is a LineString. So if I understand correctly, I would need to convert that to a MultiLineString. To do this, would I separate the coordinates pairwise to create a MultiLineString`? 2. Apologies, I saw the thread was closed and couldn't receive answers, so thought I had to redo the question.

Maybe they do not overlap exactly.
Try buffering the "eraser" with a very small distance and with flat cap style. then difference using the buffered polygon

You need to use geopandas.overlay with how="difference" instead of geopandas.difference.
If the routes don't match the bike lane file perfectly, which is probably the case, you can buffer the bike lanes before subtracting them. Exact distances are not possible using geographic coordinates, but as it is just to have a margin for inaccuracies, an approximation might be OK. I also added this in the sample script below.
As there is no easily downloaded route data provided, I create some route data artificially based on the bike lane data.
Sample script:
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely import box, LineString

# Prepare test data
# -----------------
# Read the bike lanes
bike_lanes = "https://ckan0.cf.opendata.inter.prod-toronto.ca/dataset/cycling-network/resource/bbf642be-a166-499e-9181-5a5b5223b37b/download/cycling-network.geojson"
bike_lanes_gdf = gpd.read_file(bike_lanes)

# Artificial route: the direct path + all bike lanes intersecting the direct path
route_direct_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[LineString([[-79.3873, 43.65049], [-79.3641171, 43.6613642]])],
    crs=bike_lanes_gdf.crs,
)
route_lane_gdf = bike_lanes_gdf.sjoin(route_direct_gdf, how="inner")
route_gdf = pd.concat([route_direct_gdf, route_lane_gdf])

# Routes that don't intersect with a bike lane
# --------------------------------------------
# Filter bike lanes that can intersect with the route
roi_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[box(*route_direct_gdf.total_bounds)], crs=bike_lanes_gdf.crs
)
bike_lanes_roi_gdf = bike_lanes_gdf.sjoin(roi_gdf, how="inner")
# Buffer the bike lanes to have some margin if they aren't exactly the same as the route
# The data is in geographic coordinates, so a distance is problematic. However, as it
# doesn't need to be exact... use a rough approximation.
distance = 2 / 100_000
bike_lanes_roi_gdf.geometry = bike_lanes_roi_gdf.buffer(distance, cap_style="flat")
# Apply difference
route_no_lane_gdf = route_gdf.overlay(bike_lanes_roi_gdf, how="difference")

# Plot input and result
ax = bike_lanes_roi_gdf.plot(color="blue")
route_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color="red")
route_no_lane_gdf.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow", linestyle="dashed")
plt.show()

Result:
In yellow dashed line, the result.


Although it highlights the streets used, it is not exactly what I am looking for.
